# I want to compare two properties files line by line and want to generate output.txt file with Modified, Deleted properties separately

Tags: java, file, properties

This this code i used to generate,i am getting output file with combination of modified and deleted properties but i need them separately.
basically output like

Modified properties

"original property" - "modified property"

Deleted propertied

"Property"

please help me out from this

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Set;


    public class FC {

        private Properties prop1 = null;
        private Properties prop2 = null;
        private Properties prop3 = null;
        private Properties prop4 = null;

        public FC(){

            InputStream is1 = null;
            InputStream is2 = null;
            InputStream is3 = null;
            InputStream is4 = null;

            try {
                this.prop1 = new Properties();
                is1 = new FileInputStream("C:\\new\\pranu.properties");
                prop1.load(is1);

                this.prop2 = new Properties();
                is2 = new FileInputStream("C:\\prop\\pranu1.properties");
                prop2.load(is2);


                this.prop3 = new Properties();
                is3 = new FileInputStream("C:\\new\\pranu3.properties");
                prop3.load(is3);

                this.prop4 = new Properties();
                is4 = new FileInputStream("C:\\prop\\pranu4.properties");
                prop4.load(is4);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public Set<Object> getAllKeysProp1(){
            Set<Object> keys = prop1.keySet();
            return keys;
        }  

        public Set<Object> getAllKeysProp2(){
            Set<Object> keys = prop2.keySet();
            return keys;

        }

        public Set<Object> getAllKeysProp3(){
            Set<Object> keys = prop3.keySet();
            return keys;
        }

        public Set<Object> getAllKeysProp4(){
            Set<Object> keys = prop4.keySet();
            return keys;
        }

        public static void main(String a[]){
            FC mpc = new FC();

            List<String> a1 = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> a2 = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> a3 = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> a4 = new ArrayList<String>();

            Set<Object> keys = mpc.getAllKeysProp1();
            for(Object k:keys){
                String key = (String)k;
                a1.add(key);
            }

            Set<Object> keys2 = mpc.getAllKeysProp2();
            for(Object k:keys2){
                String key = (String)k;
                a2.add(key);
            }

            a2.removeAll(a1);

            Set<Object> keys3 = mpc.getAllKeysProp1();
            for(Object k:keys3){
                String key = (String)k;
                a3.add(key);
            }

           Set<Object> keys4 = mpc.getAllKeysProp2();
                for(Object k:keys4){
                    String key = (String)k;
                    a4.add(key);   

            }

            a3.removeAll(a4);

            a2.addAll(a3);

            List<String> a5 = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> a6 = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> a7 = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> a8 = new ArrayList<String>();

            Set<Object> keys5 = mpc.getAllKeysProp3();
            for(Object k:keys5){
                String key = (String)k;
                a5.add(key);

            }    

            Set<Object> keys6 = mpc.getAllKeysProp4();
            for(Object k:keys6){
                String key = (String)k;
                a6.add(key);   
            }

            a6.removeAll(a5);

            Set<Object> keys7 = mpc.getAllKeysProp3();
            for(Object k:keys7){
                String key = (String)k;
                a7.add(key);   
            }

            Set<Object> keys8 = mpc.getAllKeysProp4();
            for(Object k:keys8){
                String key = (String)k;
                a8.add(key);
            }

            a7.removeAll(a8);

            a7.addAll(a6);

            System.out.println(a2+"\n"+a7);
            System.out.println("Comparision Report generated in C Drive under Props folder");



      //create a file first    
        try {
            PrintStream outputfile = new PrintStream(new File("C:\\props\\CR.txt"));
            System.setOut(outputfile);
            String part1 = "These Properties are missed or modified in your pranu file";
            String part2 = "These properties are missed or modified in your pranu3 file";
            outputfile.print(part1+"\n"+a2+"\n"+part2+"\n"+a7);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        }
            }
```

Comment: whats the problem with this code ?

Comment: You should have a look at the `Properties` class in the standard lib: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html especially at the method `keys()` it iherits from HashSet.

Comment: @javaguy no problem in this code it is working fine but i just want to divide properties what i mentioned like above.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle - Yes it is inherits from HashSet but here i want to separate properties like                                                                                                              Modified properties

"original property" - "modified property"

Deleted propertied

"Property"

Comment: @Pranu So then load both files in separate `Properties` objects and get the keys from one. Then iterate over the keys and fetch the values from both properties object for each key. Then you can decide if the values differ or if the "other" value is `NULL` which means the key does not exist in the "other".

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Can you please elaborate by using my code and two properties---------------That would be a great help--------here i am printing keys only thats why i am asking

Comment: Guys Still i am facing problems. Please help me

Comment: @Pranu Do u still require help ? Are you able to get what is required ?

Comment: @09Q71AO534 - Have got the solution. Thanks for your response.
If possible please tell me your coding approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `java.util.PropertyResourceBundle` to load two files separately.

This class provides methods to get `keys` as `set`.

You can `iterate` this `set` to validate or do desired checks.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still looking for answer, here is the code I implemented

```
public class PropertiesCompare {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

    String propertiesFilename1 = System.getProperty("PropFile1");
    String propertiesFilename2 = System.getProperty("PropFile2");

    Map<String, String> PropFile1 = getProps(propertiesFilename1);
    Map<String, String> PropFile2 = getProps(propertiesFilename2);

    String missingProp = "";

    for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : PropFile1.entrySet()) {
        if (PropFile2.containsKey(entry.getKey())) {
            String PropFile2Value = (PropFile2.get(entry.getKey()));
            String PropFile1Value = (entry.getValue());

            if (!PropFile2Value.equalsIgnoreCase(PropFile1Value)) {
                 System.out.println("Key : "+entry.getKey()+"\t\nValue : PropFile1 = "+PropFile1Value+", PropFile2 = "+PropFile2Value);
            }
        } else {
            missingProp= missingProp+(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue() + "\n");
        }
    }
}

public static Map<String, String> getProps(String propertiesFilename1) {
    Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
    try (InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(propertiesFilename1)) {
        Properties prop = new Properties() {
            @Override
            public synchronized Object put(Object key, Object value) {
                return properties.put(key.toString(), value.toString());
            }
        };
        prop.load(stream);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return properties;
  }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you wants to see the diff between 2 collections

you can use com.google.common.collect.Sets.difference(Set set1, Set set2)

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more on your question ? Add code formatting and explain how the code in your answer should be used